# Redirecting std output from Process object to file in .net

Tags: .net, file, process

Is there a simple way how to launch a process in .NET and redirect its output(s) to a file? 
I know that in Win API I can pass a file handle to the `CreateProcess` function.
In .NET I can do something like

```
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

and then use `BeginOutputReadLine` and `StandardOutput` to get the data and save it to a file. But it seems a bit overhead compared to what OS can handle itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but this pointed me to a better answer: [Capturing binary output from Process.StandardOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143281/capturing-binary-output-from-process-standardoutput)

```
Process cmdProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
cmdStartInfo.FileName = "samtools";

cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

cmdStartInfo.Arguments = "view -u " + BamFileName + " " + chromosome + ":" + start + "-" + end;

cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
cmdProcess.Start();

using (FileStream str = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    cmdProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(str);
}
```

If you want to do this asynchronously, you can use CopyToAsync instead and either await the returned task or add a ContinueWith to finish off. This works great for me.

Comment: Bonus points for the fact that your example is using samtools (something I've been using all day today =])

Answer (score 0):

you can run file as `someApp.exe >logfile.txt`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't run this from .NET. I could run something like "cmd.exe /c someApp.exe > file.txt" but that's still a workaround.

Comment: @Elephantik yes, it might be required. What you want is essentially workaround.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that a feature supported by OS is workaround ;)

Comment: @Elephantik i don't understand you. this method is pretty valid.

Comment: I need to run it from the .NET environment. Not from cmd.exe

Comment: @Elephantik you can run it from .net this way