# Getting Binary Data from StandardOutput

Tags: c#, process, binary-data, redirectstandardoutput

I'm starting a process with code similar to that below:

```
// some of the flags are not needed
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
process.ErrorDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
process.Start();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();

void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
}

void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that the `DataReceivedEventArgs` object has a `Data` property which is a string. I need to read the standard output data as the binary data it is. I'm guessing there's no way to get the string data back into it's appropriate binary data, so any suggestions on using a different method for receiving the binary data would be great.

Comment: See "Capturing binary output from Process.StandardOutput" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143281/capturing-binary-output-from-process-standardoutput), although that uses a pull approach, not push (with the OutputDataReceived event handler), as you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bradley Grainger who made a comment on the question was right. The event handlers don't support retrieving binary data from standard out. Had to switch over to using a main loop and pulling data from standard out using the read functions.

Comment: Just found out the hard way.