# Connect Process StandardOutput to another Process StandardInput

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a pipeline between several Process objects.

I can run a single Process and capture its StandardOutput, but when I try to connect multiple Process objects, the second one doesn't seem to receive any data from the first one's StandardInput.

In this code, I'm using `cat`, which either prints the contents of its arguments to stdout, or just copies stdin to stdout.

Using one process works fine:

```
// Works
private async void launchButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var outputBuffer = new MemoryStream();

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    Process process1;

    {
        process1 = new Process();

        process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cat.exe";
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "K:\\temp\\streams.txt";
        process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process1.Start();
    }

    tasks.Add(process1.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(outputBuffer));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    // OK: This prints the contents of the file
    Console.WriteLine("Final output: {0}", UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputBuffer.GetBuffer()));

}
```

But when I add a second process and try to copy Process1's StandardOutput to Process2's StandardInput, I don't ever get any output from Process2 and the await never completes:

```
// Doesn't work
private async void launchButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var outputBuffer = new MemoryStream();

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    Process process1, process2;

    {
        process1 = new Process();

        process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cat.exe";
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "K:\\temp\\streams.txt";
        process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process1.Start();
    }

    {
        process2 = new Process();

        process2.StartInfo.FileName = "cat.exe";
        process2.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        process2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process2.Start();
    }

    tasks.Add(process1.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(process2.StandardInput.BaseStream));
    tasks.Add(process2.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(outputBuffer));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // Never returns!

    Console.WriteLine("Final output: {0}", UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputBuffer.GetBuffer()));

}
```

Doing something like this works fine from the command line:

```
C:\>cat.exe K:\temp\streams.txt | cat.exe
... contents of file ...

C:\>
```

I tried adding Exited event handlers to these Process objects. Process1 exits fine, but Process2 never exits.

I tried some other commands too (like sed), but Process2 still never seems to do anything.

I'm using the streams' BaseStream properties, because I will eventually be working with binary data. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535927/339378) This also means I can't use `OutputDataReceived`, which returns a string (and that would be more complicated anyway).

Thanks!

Comment: you may want to set up your process input and output before running start

Comment: @gashach You can't use StandardOutput/Input before starting the process or you get an exception: "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."

Comment: ok, how about using the standartinput property on process2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `CopyToAsync` doesn't close the output stream on completion. This didn't matter for my MemoryStream, but obviously I need to close a process's StandardInput or it won't ever complete.

I made this method:

```
private static async Task CopyThenClose(Stream from, Stream to)
{
    await from.CopyToAsync(to);
    to.Close();
}
```

And replaced the calls to `CopyToAsync`; eg.:

```
tasks.Add(CopyThenClose(process1.StandardOutput.BaseStream, process2.StandardInput.BaseStream));
```