# Get Binary Output and Errors text of a process

Tags: c#, process, binary, redirectstandardoutput

I want to run an exe utility which produces some binary output (which is an image) based on given parameters. 
I need to get the binary **output** of the utility as a stream (`MemoryStream`) and the **Errors** (if any).
It is also required to have a **Timeout** such that if app hangs or it takes a long time to respond, break its execution and return what ever result it output until that time.

One way is to use cmd like as:

```
cmd /C ... >out.jpg 2>err.txt
```

But this requires a temp file which is not acceptable, i want to capture output data directly as it should be called many times and output size is large.

The basic code to run the process is as following:

```
using (var p = new Process())
{
    //p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/C " + command + " > x.jpg 2> err.txt");
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = @"x.exe", //dcraw
        Arguments = @"-c -e x.jpg", 
        UseShellExecute = false, //it is usefull for non-exe like as for a Word file.
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };
    int timeout = 5000; //msec

    p.Start();

    //MemoryStream outputStream = ...
    //p.OutputDataReceived += ... //can't use this as it returns text not binary data

    //string errorText = ...

    p.WaitForExit();

    //return new pResult(Image.FromStream(outputStream), errorText, isTimedout, ...);

}
```

How to get outputStream and errorText with specified timeout?

Note: I know there are several questions about `process.start` and output redirecting. Most of them are about capturing text output not binary data (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4291912/2803565) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139593/2803565)). And this [binary question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4143281/2803565) does not answer my question completely as stated here (capturing both output and errors at the same time may cause dead-end locks, no timeout specified).

Comment: I/O redirection is a pretty leaky abstraction that should have stayed in Unix.  It cannot be binary, only readable text encoded in a code page that uses 8-bit code units can redirect correctly.  Having both programs agree about the encoding to use is in itself a gritty problem.  Generate a file instead, pass the file path as an argument.  Using a pipe or socket is not impossible, hard to test.

Comment: @HansPassant but i think it is possible to capture output as binary if i don't care about capturing the errors too. eg: using `Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream`. so the encoding should not be an issue