# Start-Process -RedirectStandardInput $null -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "myprogram.exe arg1 arg2"

Tags: powershell

What's the powershell equivalent of unix "< /dev/null" when using start-process?  In unix i would do: "myprogram.exe arg1 arg2 < /dev/null":

I tried the same in powershell using start-process:

```
 Start-Process -RedirectStandardInput $null -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "myprogram.exe arg1 arg2"
```

Error message, it doesn't work:

```
Start-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'RedirectStandardInput'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or
empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:38
+ Start-Process -RedirectStandardInput $null -FilePath powershell.exe - ...
+                                      ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Process], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: How about `$null | myprogram arg1 arg2`?

Comment: does it work with start-process?

Comment: I was thinking of cheating:  $null > stuff.txt;  start-process -RedirectStandardInput stuff.txt -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "gci"

Answer (score 1):

**With *direct, synchronous* invocation:**

```sh
# Provide empty stdin input to myprogram.exe
# Equivalent to the following in a Unix shell:
#     myprogram.exe arg1 arg2 </dev/null
@() | myprogram.exe arg1 arg2
```

Note:

- `$null`, as [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) suggests, works too, but only with *external programs* - a *PowerShell* command would receive an actual `$null` as input.
- By contrast, `@()` (an empty array) consistently sends *nothing* through the pipeline (external programs receive pipeline input via stdin), because it is the *elements* of the array that are being sent, one by one - if any - and an empty array by definition has no elements).

---

**With an *asynchronous-by-default* [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call**:

Note:

- `Start-Process` is only needed in *unusual* invocation scenarios, such as needing to launch a command in a *new* console window (including with elevation) or needing to run with a different user identity); for synchronous execution of CLIs with their streams connected to PowerShell's, use the direct-invocation technique shown above. For guidance on when `Start-Process` is or isn't appropriate, see [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239).

As of PowerShell 7.2, you can only pass *file paths* to `Start-Process`' `-Redirect*` parameters.

- [GitHub issue #5184](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5184) suggests a potential future enhancement that would also allow use of *variables*, using notation such as `variable:null`

Therefore, to **effectively pass empty stdin input via `Start-Process`, you must indeed use `-RedirectStandardInput` with a (temporary) *empty file* (`0` bytes)**, as shown in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70509900/45375).

- On *Unix*-like platforms, where you *should* be able to use `-RedirectStandardInput /dev/null`, that doesn't work as of PowerShell 7.2.1 due to a long-standing *bug*: instead of *no* stdin input, a *newline* is sent - see [GitHub issue #8702](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8702). That said, `Start-Process` is rarely useful on Unix, due to its inability there to launch a process in a *new window*.
- **On Windows, deleting the temporary file unfortunately requires *waiting for the launched program to exit***, because the file is locked until then.
  Therefore, in order to reliably clean up a temporary file used this way you'll have to either use:

  - `-Wait`, to make the call synchronous
  - `-PassThru`, to have a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) returned that you can later monitor for whether the process has exited (via `.HasExited` or `.WaitForExit()`).

However, there is a **workaround**: Call via `cmd.exe` and use *its* `<NUL` redirection (the equivalent of `</dev/null` in Unix):

```sh
# Parameters -FilePath and -ArgumentList positionally implied.
Start-Process cmd.exe '/c "myprogram.exe arg1 arg2 <NUL"'
```

Or, if you need a new PowerShell instance anyway, you can use its direct-invocation syntax in the command line you pass:

```sh
Start-Process powershell.exe '-c "@() | myprogram.exe arg1 arg2"'
```

Note:

- The `cmd`-based workaround is faster and more light-weight, and therefore the better choice if the invocation of `myprogram.exe` is the only required operation.
- More generally, delegating to `cmd.exe`'s pipeline and redirection operators (and, analogously, to `/bin/sh`'s on Unix) is a workaround to get around the limitation that PowerShell's pipelines currently cannot serve as *raw byte conduits*, resulting in data corruption if an attempt is made to capture raw byte output with `>`, for instance; ditto with `Start-Process`' `-Redirect*` parameters - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).
- With extra effort detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535927/45375), you can also achieve raw byte processing via the `System.Diagnostics.Process`-related .NET APIs shown below.

---

With **direct use of the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process)-related *.NET APIs***:

**Note**:

- You won't be able to launch the process in a *new console window* this way, because that would require the [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) instance's `.UseShellExecute` property to be set to `$true`, which use of `.RedirectStandardInput` *precludes*.

```sh
# Configure the process to launch.
$ps = [System.Diagnostics.Process] @{
  StartInfo = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo] @{ 
    FileName = 'myprogram.exe'
    Arguments = 'arg1 arg2'
    UseShellExecute = $false # Required for use of .Redirect* properties
    RedirectStandardInput = $true # Provide stdin input programmatically below
    WorkingDirectory = $PWD.ProviderPath # Use PowerShell's current dir.
  }
}

$null = $ps.Start() # Launch asynchronously
$ps.StandardInput.Close() # Close stdin, effectively providing no input.
$ps.WaitForExit()  # Wait for the process to exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's got to be a better way:

```
PS> $temp = New-TemporaryFile
PS> start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "gci C:\" -nnw -wait -RedirectStandardInput $temp
```

this works but it will create a million empty files in the temp folder to purge.

Another possibility:

```
PS> start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "`$null `| gci C:\" -nnw -wait
```